# View: Comparison taxonomy terms

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have a content type = news and 5 normal page.
Content type news have 5 taxonomy term that the user can select and chose when write a news.
Each of the 5 normal page have 1 taxonomy term on it.

I want do a view (block) that show only the news that have the same taxonomy term.

My previous solution was to do a view for each taxonomy term but i don't like it because i have 5 block.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that [Contextual Filters](http://dannyenglander.com/blog/using-views-contextual-filters-create-related-content-block-drupal-7) are what you are looking for. The example should be pretty close to your use case from the sound of it.